# Text folding in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Can I hide some pieces of text under something clickable and open them up when mouse is clicked?

Comment: No, you can't do something like that, at least natively.

Answer (score 5):

They say that **you cannot**. But, you can work it around to some extent -- **comments!** Yes, you can comment the 'hyperlink' and click it to show up the hidden text on the margins.

Comment: What do you mean by *comment the 'hyperlink'*?  And how is the text hidden?

Comment: the lack of the ability to create arbitrary foldable nested lists seems to be the bane of all word processing applications

Comment: What makes it worse is, that exact functionality (nested collapsible lists) is displayed right at the start of the "Mother of All Demos" in December 1968.  That proof of concept was *fifty* years ago now and we still don't get to use it.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman Yes, well... those engineers would rather have died than have poor responsiveness on their single digit MHz CPU, while now it's shamefully considered acceptable for a multi-core, multi-Ghz CPU to not response just as instantly (for instance, to come out of sleep)

Comment: @Michael Microsoft OneNote provides that feature. Not sure it can be considered as a word processing app though.

Comment: emacs has it. We have been going backwards. Everything is getting worse.